# FreeRTOS+TCP and mbedTLS+TCP

Tags: ssl, networking, tcp, freertos, mbedtls

I have program which performs successful transfer of data between client(washing machine) and server(HawkBit) by using FreeRTOS+TCP in which we have sockets from FreeRTOS only but now I want to implement TLS over it for which I am using mbedTLS in which we again have function for TCP connections, functions for socket opening closing, every function which we have in FreeRTOS again now I don't know what should I do...!is there any possibility of using the socket from FreeRTOS+TCP and just make CA certification from mbedTLS on the top of it! or I need to implement again everything with mbedTLS what I have implemented before with freeRTOS!

Answer (score 0):

This is using FreeRTOS+TCP through a TLS abstraction https://github.com/aws/amazon-freertos/blob/master/libraries/abstractions/secure_sockets/freertos_plus_tcp/iot_secure_sockets.c - and this is the implementation of the abstraction layer for mbedTLS https://github.com/aws/amazon-freertos/blob/master/libraries/freertos_plus/standard/tls/src/iot_tls.c